# Creating custom personas within AEM 6.3

Tags: aem, aem-6

I've just started learning AEM and more specifically, how to use Context Hub. There are a number of pre-fab personas that I can use to ensure that any targeting I employ will reach particular audiences, but some of my parameters I have set for specific audiences are too specific for the generic built in personas to accurately test.

How can I go about creating my own custom personas to use for testing within AEM's Context Hub?

Comment: You can create new Personas from Tools>Users>Create on AEM Author instance.